# SQL Server CONTAINS Predicate - using a column value as the <contains_condition>

Tags: sql-server, contains

I'm having a problem rewriting an existing process that uses `CONTAINS` predicate.  The existing process is working using a `CURSOR`, but it's really slow, and getting slower as more data is inserted.

I have made up a simple example (code below) containing two tables - one is **Full Text Indexed**, and the other has a column which identifies a `CONTAINS` condition to choose rows from the first.

The current stored procedure uses a `CURSOR` to loop through the second table, setting a `@filter` variable, then uses `CONTAINS` to locate the rows from the first table that match.  The problem is that it runs for hours, and it's getting worse.

To speed the process up, I tried to use the `CONTAINS` predicate directly on the column value rather than going through the pain of a cursor... but I'm getting a syntax error.  My example is below.

I've tried to implement a `CROSS APPLY` and I've also tried to write a User-Defined Function (`fnCONTAINS`) with no luck.

```
IF ( object_id('Players') IS NOT NULL )
  DROP TABLE Players

go

IF ( object_id('TeamNeeds') IS NOT NULL )
  DROP TABLE TeamNeeds

go

-- create fulltext catalog ft as default
go

CREATE TABLE Players
  (
     PlayerID        INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     PlayerName      VARCHAR(20),
     PlayerPositions VARCHAR(60)
  )

go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXPlayerID
  ON Players( PlayerID )

go

CREATE fulltext INDEX ON Players(PlayerPositions) KEY INDEX IXPlayerID

go

INSERT Players
       (PlayerName,
        PlayerPositions)
VALUES( 'Patrick Travers',
        'Pitcher,Left Field,Center Field,Right Field,Shortstop' )

go

CREATE TABLE TeamNeeds
  (
     TeamID   INT,
     Keywords VARCHAR(50)
  )

go

INSERT TeamNeeds
       (TeamID,
        Keywords)
VALUES( 1,
        '"Center Field" and "Shortstop" and "Pitcher"' )

go

WAITFOR delay '00:00:05'

go -- Give the Full Text Index process time to populate the catalog
SELECT PlayerID,
       PlayerName,
       PlayerPositions
FROM   Player,
       TeamNeeds
WHERE  CONTAINS(PlayerPositions, Keywords)

go -- Syntax error on Keywords...
SELECT PlayerID,
       PlayerName,
       PlayerPositions
FROM   Players,
       TeamNeeds
WHERE  CONTAINS(PlayerPositions, '"Center Field" and "Shortstop" and "Pitcher"')

go -- Works just fine, but requires setting an explicit search expression for every search, which is terribly slow
```

Comment: I removed the Comment-separator so make your code more readable.

Comment: I have been also looking to answer this question.  I looked though stackoverflow and ms's documentation, but it looks like you cant do CONTAINS(table1.col, table2.col).  You can only do CONTAINS(table1.col, 'text') or CONTAINS(table1.col, @some_text).  I hope someone comes and proves me wrong.

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve this problem? I am having exactly same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible with a multi statement TVF as far as I can see.

Creating the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ft_test] (@Keywords VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE (
  PlayerID        INT,
  PlayerName      VARCHAR(20),
  PlayerPositions VARCHAR(60))
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
      SELECT PlayerID,
             PlayerName,
             PlayerPositions
      FROM   Players
      WHERE  CONTAINS(PlayerPositions, @Keywords)

      RETURN
  END
```

Then the following works fine

```
SELECT *
FROM   TeamNeeds
       CROSS APPLY [dbo].[ft_test] (Keywords) CA
```

Though the inline version fails with "The inline function "x" cannot take correlated parameters or subqueries because it uses a full-text operator."